# Restrict Uppercase in input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, redmine

I have a JS where I can detect if uppercase is being entered, but I'm unable to convert the text text to lower case. i have used CSS `text-transform: lowercase;` but this shows that it's lower but once submitted, it shows the text as normal (original format).
I have tried with jquery `toLowerCase();` but I don't know what I have missed here coz it didn't work.
this is my script,

```
  const setup = function(fieldSelector) {
    const field = $(fieldSelector);
    const upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');
    const applyStyle = function() {
      if (field.val().match(upperCase)) {
        field.val().toLowerCase();
      } else {
        field.val();
      }
    };
    field.on('change', applyStyle);
    applyStyle();
  }
  // Note: Change the ID according to the custom field you want to target.
  setup('#issue_custom_field_values_17');
});
```

this code is used for redmine "View customize plugin"

Comment: what is redmine

Comment: You only need to change the text when submitting it. Otherwise, you'll be preventing user from normally editing the field since the cursor will be jumping to the last position.

Comment: *I have used CSS text-transform: lowercase;* - css changes how it's *displayed* - add the css to your output as well.

Comment: `str.toLowerCase()` - strings are immutable - they don't change.  This provides you with a new string, so needs to be `str = str.toLowerCase()` or `field.val(field.val().toLowerCase())`

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI redmine is an open source issue tracking you can learn more on redmine.org

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the job for you

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
 let val = $(this).val().toLowerCase()
 $(this).val(val)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const char = string.charAt(field.val());
const isUpperCaseLetter = (/[A-Z]/.test(char));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of the field to the new lowercase value on change

```
 const setup = function(fieldSelector) {
        const field = $(fieldSelector);
        const upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');
        // Here's the change
        const applyStyle = function() {
         field.val( field.val().toLowerCase() )
        };
        field.on('change', applyStyle);
        applyStyle();
      }
      // Note: Change the ID according to the custom field you want to target.
      setup('#issue_custom_field_values_17');
    });
```